# How to set width 100% in percentage in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $(".slider").slideshow({
        width: 1920,
        height: 710,
        transition: 'SquareRandom'
    });
    $(".caption").fadeIn(500);

    // playing with events:

    $(".slider").bind("sliderChange", function (event, curSlide) {
        $(curSlide).children(".caption").hide();
    });

    $(".slider").bind("sliderTransitionFinishes", function (event, curSlide) {
        $(curSlide).children(".caption").fadeIn(500);
    });
});
```

I am using this code for my complete page slider i want to rotate my full page with logo and mwnues and here in this code i have fixed height and width i dont want to make it fixed i want to it 100%.

Comment: width: $(window).width()

Answer (score 3):

Try changing your width and height options to equal the width and height of the parent window:

```
$(".slider").slideshow({
        width: $(window).width() +"px",
        height: $(window).height()+"px",
        transition: 'SquareRandom'
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Also you can do this with Pure CSS:**

```
.slider {
 width: 100%!important
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('.slider').css('width', '');
```

Remove the width property give the element full width with its container